# Как распространять программу на питоне?

Tags: python

Я написал небольшое cli приложение, главная проблема в том, что для его работы используются некоторые быблиотеки (requests.py и его зависимости)

Теперь вопрос, а как это распространять? Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь (независимо от платформы!!!) мог просто скачать что-то вроде final_app.py, закинуть его в path и спокойно вызывать через консоль.

Наличие самого питона у пользователя будет, это в данном случае данность

Comment: Скомпилировать все в один исполняемый файл, для начала. [Такое](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/publish-python-packages.html) нашел -

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3656628/6-ways-to-package-python-apps-for-re-use.html

Comment: можно попробовать каждый импорт обернуть в `try: import ... except ImportError:os.system("pip install ...")`